# How to rerun my program in vb6?

Tags: vb6

How to rerun (close then run)  my program in vb6

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is probably to create a "watcher" application that you launch in your main app before terminating it.

First, the main app should create a mutex or semaphore upon launch. When you want to do the app restart, have the main app launch the watcher. The watcher application should wait until the main application mutex/semaphore is gone, then re-launch the main application.

I recently released a semaphore class written in VB6 which would take care of some of the hard work: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=634635

Answer (score 0):

Stop the currently running executable( click the button with a square block image on it on the IDE ) and then shift+F5, to restart the program.

Comment: I mean restart the exe program

Comment: By "restart the exe program" I understand that there is already a running window that needs to be stopped before running the program again. Did I get you wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be to create a batch file that starts the executable. Call this with an asynchronous call.

You will then need a littlembit of logic to check that you don't have two instances running at once. If there., the new one can wait a second or so. If it is still there, a user warning can be given.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Main Project :

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
Call Shell(App.Path & "\Restart.exe", 1)

End Sub
```

Restart project :

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Const WM_CLOSE = &H10

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim WinWnd As Long

    WinWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Form1") 'Replace Form1 with Whatever your Form's Caption is

    If WinWnd <> 0 Then
        PostMessage WinWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0&, 0&
    Else
        MsgBox "No window of that name exists."
    End If

    Call Shell("Main.exe", 1)

End Sub
```

found here http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?600511-RESOLVED-Application-restarting-itself