# Error -2147417848 at VB.Forms.Add call over COM

Tags: com, vb6

I have a .NET application that references a VB6 legacy DLL.  The legacy DLL has a class with a public method.  Inside this public method it's trying to find an existing form by name, or create it if it doesn't exist:

```
Set objForm = GetForm(strFormName)

If objForm Is Nothing Then

    'Creates a new instance of the form
    Set objForm = VB.Forms.Add(strFormName)

End If
```

... where `GetForm` is:

```
Private Function GetForm(ByVal strFormName As String) As Form

    Dim objForm As Form

    For Each objForm In VB.Forms
        If objForm.Name = strFormName Then
            Set GetForm = objForm
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    Set GetForm = Nothing

End Function
```

It's raising an error at this line:

```
Set objForm = VB.Forms.Add(strFormName)
```

The error is:

```
Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.   
Error#-2147417848(80010108)
```

Note that `strFormName` is a valid form name, and this public method call works *almost all the time*.  It just very occasionally happens to raise this error.

I would like to know what is causing this error, or what else can I do to track it down further?

Comment: You know of this article? http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q319832

Comment: @Dabblernl - yes, I saw that.  I don't think it applies.  I'm using a fully qualified reference (`VB.Forms.Add`).  It's also talking about it working the first time and failing on subsequent calls, but this works first, second, third time, but sometimes just randomly fails.

Comment: Do you have any `Global`s?

Comment: @retailcoder - yes, there are legacy global variables.  I think they're all fundamental types (`Integer`, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q319832) that @Dabblernl linked is very relevant to this problem.  The VB.Forms collection is exactly such an unqualified reference.  It acts like a global variable, you can use VB.Forms anywhere in VB6 code without providing an object reference.

Under the hood, the VB6 runtime creates the Forms collection the very first time you create a form and stores this collection object so that future references to VB.Forms uses the exact same collection.  What the error code means is that you use that collection *after it was destroyed*.

It isn't very clear exactly when that happens, this is all internal plumbing for the VB6 runtime support library.  But normally, a VB6 app terminates when the last form gets unloaded.  What is different in your case is that the lifetime of your process is no longer controlled by the VB6 runtime.  .NET controls it now.

So, extrapolating, there are good odds that the VB6 runtime has decided that the Forms collection is no longer needed and destroyed it and that your .NET code may create a new Form, later, thus triggering the error.

If this is at all accurate then you'll need to take a counter-measure to prevent this from happening.  One possible way to do so is to ensure that there is always at least one VB6 form around to keep the collection valid.  It doesn't have to be a visible one.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is intermittent and very seldom as mentioned in OP, retrying may work around it:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Sub SomeProcedure()
Dim attempts As Integer
On Error Goto ErrHandler

    Set objForm = GetForm(strFormName)
    If objForm Is Nothing Then

        'Creates a new instance of the form
        Set objForm = VB.Forms.Add(strFormName)

    End If

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = -2147417848 Then
        attempts = attempts + 1
        If attempts < 10 Then
            Err.Clear
            Sleep 55
            Debug.Print "Automation error. Retry attempt: " & attempts
            Resume
        End If
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'this should run after the 10th failed attempt
        MsgBox Err.Message
        Err.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

It's not solving the problem, but it may stop your app from crashing because of it...

Comment: I will try it, but it seems that once this happens, it's permanent until you restart the application.

Comment: Then this smells like it's the `VB.Forms` object that's *disconnected*. If that's the case, consider launching this program from an "overhead watcher" that can start a fresh new instance (perhaps with command-line args to restore some state) when this happens (perhaps catch a particular exception). Found clues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579348/how-to-rerun-my-program-in-vb6

Comment: this VB6 dll is exposing itself as a COM object and being run from .NET code.  It's new'ing up the COM object every time it calls the code above.  I think the only way to "restart" it would be to somehow unload the DLL and reload it, but I don't think that's possible.